# Meteor renderList intercept? client side

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have chat messages displayed like this:

```
  {{#each msg}}
    {{> chatMsg}}
  {{/each}}
```

When users enter the chat I add a document to the collection with `user joins the chat`. When a user rapidly reenters and leaves the chat I don't want to duplicate `user joins the chat` over and over again. I want to display something like `user joins the chat x3`.

Is there a way to do this on the client side by hooking into renderList? I know I can change the doc on the server side but it seems unnecessarily intensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get there from here is to write a custom publisher.  Instead of just returning a cursor from your publish function, call observe() on your cursor within the publish function, and do the appropriate set(), unset(), and flush() calls within that, that do the appropriate multiplying a previous message instead of adding a new one.   You can find the relevant documentation at the [meteor documentation for Meteor.publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish)

To get a basis from comparison, you can look at the current code to publish a Cursor, which is  in packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js, in Cursor.prototype._publishCursor.

Note: My answer here is for Meteor 0.5.2.  The API for custom publishers is going to be changing in a future release of Meteor, and there will be different functions you have to call than set() unset() and flush()

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make a method call that just updates the latest user joined message.

```
function formatJoinMessage(username,count) {...}

if (Meteor.isServer) Meteor.startup(function () {Chats._ensureIndex({modified:-1}); ...});

Meteor.methods({
    join:function() {
        var joinMessage = Chats.find({type:MESSAGE_TYPE_JOINED,userId:this.userId}).sort({modified:-1}).fetch()[0];
        if (joinMessage)
            Chats.update({_id:joinMessage._id},{$inc:{joins:1},$set:{text:formatJoinMessage(this.userId,joinMessage.joins+1),modified:new Date()});
        else
            Chats.insert({user:this.userId,joins:1,modified:new Date(),text:formatJoinMessage(this.userId,1)});
    }
)};
```

Don't want to change the server doc? That's okay, but conceptually a chat join isn't a chat message. So you should definitely have a `meta` field for stuff like this in your `chat` documents.

But supposing you don't want to do that. I'd do something like this:

```
var userIdToName = function(userId) {...}; // some kind of userId to name helper

Template.chatroom.msg = function() {
  var messages = Chat.findOne(Session.get("currentChat")).messages; // msg in your code?
  return _.reduce(messages,function (newMessages, currentMessage) {
    var lastMsg = newMessages[newMessages.length-1];
    if (currentMessage.type == MESSAGE_TYPES_JOIN) {
       if (lastMsg && lastMsg.type == MESSAGE_TYPES_JOIN && currentMessage.user == lastMsg.user) {
          currentMessage.timesJoined = lastMsg.timesJoined+1;
          newMessages.shift();
       } else {
          currentMessage.timesJoined = 1;
       }
       currentMessage.chatMsg = userIdToName(lastMsg.user) + " joins the chat &mult;" + currentMessage.timesJoined.toString();
    }
    return newMessages.concat(currentMessage);
  },[]);
}
```

This is a bit of a doozy. Suffice it to say, it "reduces" all the join messages it finds in the chat's current messages down to one message. You dynamically add the property `timesJoined`; it does not appear in the document. But you should have a `type` field that lets you know the difference between a join message and a regular message is.

If you don't even have that metadata at minimum, then your chat application isn't going to work very well. Don't hesitate to change your model!

Comment: You're storing chat messages as embeded docs on one document? That can't work. (4mb mongo document limit)

Comment: Hmm, I think it's 32 MBs (?), but yes there are limitations. Chat systems actually don't translate well into NoSQL schema. I think this limitation isn't a deal breaker though... Who's going to generate 4MB of chat conversation in one day? That's writing a book! But thanks for pointing out the limitations.

Comment: Also, my particular solution just achieves the GUI-computation based on your needs. I made some assumptions about your schema, but it should work on any array of messages, however they are stored. The key insight is recognizing you are "reducing" multiple messages into one message.

Comment: Yes you're right that it's not about the schema. But generally speaking I don't want to return an array because this breaks Meteor rendering. You have to return a minimongo cursor for meteor to render correctly or else meteor will rerender the entire list when new items are added instead of only adding on 1 list item.

Also it's not one day, I plan to keep the chat forever.

Comment: Hmm, you have to return something serializable (i.e., an array or object) no matter what. Returning a cursor shouldn't work—and if it does, it's just converting to `fetch()` internally. You can structure things however you'd like. You can also just check for the existence of a recent `user joined` message and modify it, using a method. That might be simplest.